# Improving code quality [Javascript / AngulaJS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made a carousel from scracth with some effects and I made it in this way:

```
    $scope.intro = {
    index : 0,
    A : false,
    B : false,
    C : false,
    D : false,
    E : false,
    F : false,
    G : false,
    H : false,
    I : false,
    L : false,
    M : false,
    N : false
};

var intervallo = 4000;
var action = function(){
    $scope.intro.N = false;
    $scope.intro.A = true;
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.intro.index++;
        $scope.intro.A = false;
        $scope.intro.B = true;
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.intro.index++;
            $scope.intro.B = false;
            $scope.intro.C = true;
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.intro.index++;
                $scope.intro.C = false;
                $scope.intro.D = true;
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.intro.index++;
                    $scope.intro.D = false;
                    $scope.intro.E = true;
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $scope.intro.index++;
                        $scope.intro.E = false;
                        $scope.intro.F = true;
                        $timeout(function () {
                            $scope.intro.index++;
                            $scope.intro.F = false;
                            $scope.intro.G = true;
                            $timeout(function () {
                                $scope.intro.index++;
                                $scope.intro.G = false;
                                $scope.intro.H = true;
                                $timeout(function () {
                                    $scope.intro.index++;
                                    $scope.intro.H = false;
                                    $scope.intro.I = true;
                                    $timeout(function () {
                                        $scope.intro.index++;
                                        $scope.intro.I = false;
                                        $scope.intro.L = true;
                                        $timeout(function () {
                                            $scope.intro.index++;
                                            $scope.intro.L = false;
                                            $scope.intro.M = true;
                                            $timeout(function () {
                                                $scope.intro.index++;
                                                $scope.intro.M = false;
                                                $scope.intro.N = true;
                                            }, intervallo);
                                        }, intervallo);
                                    }, intervallo);
                                }, intervallo);
                            }, intervallo);
                        }, intervallo);
                    }, intervallo);
                }, intervallo);
            }, intervallo);
        }, intervallo);
    }, intervallo);
};

$interval(function(){action()}, 1000, 1);
$interval(function(){action()}, (intervallo * 12) + 1000 );
```

Now, it works well, and I'm happy with that, but I'm just wondering if there is a better way to write it.
In case you want to see it in action, you can find it in: [mobiliperufficio.com](http://mobiliperufficio.com)

now the "new" code is:

```
var alphaChars = "nabcdefghilmn".toUpperCase().split("");

$scope.intro = {};
$scope.intro.index = 0;
var intervallo = 4000;

var action = function(currentChar, nextChar, i) {
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.intro[currentChar] = false;
        $scope.intro[nextChar] = true;
        $scope.intro.index = i;
    }, intervallo * i);
};

$interval(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < alphaChars.length - 1; i++) {
        action(alphaChars[i], alphaChars[i + 1], i);
    }
}, 1000, 1);
$interval(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < alphaChars.length - 1; i++) {
        action(alphaChars[i], alphaChars[i + 1], i);
    }
}, (intervallo * alphaChars.length) + 1000 );
```

many thanks

Comment: Timeoutception... How about a foreach loop?

Comment: This has to be the best thing I've seen all day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use a loop:

```
var alphaChars = "abcdefghijklmn".toUpperCase().split("");

$scope.intro.index++;
$scope.intro.A = false;
$scope.intro.B = true;

for (var i = 0; i < alphaChars.length - 1; i++) {
    (function(char, nextChar) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.intro.index++;
            $scope.intro[char] = false;
            $scope.intro[nextChar] = true;
        }, intervallo);
    })(alphaChars[i], alphaChars[i + 1])
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
It doesn't work (maybe my fault) and it's not exactly what I did with the other, but I've understood the "loop logic". 
I'll work aroud with that and I see if it can be a good hint, thank you.